# How to move soucrce code from EC2 instance to Codecommit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-codecommit

I have EC2 instance, up and running good. Now I want a copy of the source code to be moved to AWS Code commit for further development and deployment.

Basically souce code should be moved from AWS EC2 to AWS Codecommit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either SSH (if Linux), or RDP (if windows), into the machine. Turn your source directories into a git repository, and then git push it to your remote (code commit) repository.

You basically do it the exact same way you would do it from any other machine - the fact that it is an EC2 instance really doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create  a git credential from AWS IAM. You need these credential whenever you pushed your code into codecommit. Alternatively, you can also upload your SSH public key into fAWS codecommit so that you don't need to enter your credentials every time whenever you push your code.

then follow the steps mentioned bellow:

1. Type `git init` while you are on your project folder in EC2
2. Then `git add .`
3. Then type `git commit -m 'your custom commit message here'`
4. Create a repo in CodeCommit from AWS Management Console.
5. Add then from your project folder, type remote origin by typing `git remote add origin https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/testrepo` (if you using HTTPS protocol) or `git remote add origin ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/testrepo` (if you are using SSH protocol)
6. Then push your code by typing `git push origin master`. in this stage, you have to enter your credentials such as AWS username and password or don't need them if you already uploaded your SSH public key into AWS code commit.